# Jxcore add new task parallel

Tags: jxcore

I'm using jxcore to execute a job in parallel. But when I test as below

```
var method = function () {
   var sleep = require('sleep');
   console.log("thread started", process.threadId);
   sleep.sleep(2);
   console.log("thread finished", process.threadId);
};

jxcore.tasks.addTask(method);
jxcore.tasks.addTask(method);
jxcore.tasks.addTask(method);
jxcore.tasks.addTask(method);
```

Result seems just 1 thread is used :

```
thread started 0
thread finished 0
thread started 0
thread finished 0
thread started 0
thread finished 0
thread started 0
thread finished 0
```

I expect , it create 4 thread start parallel.
How can i achieve it ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Which is your operating system? And which jxcore version are you using?

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 14.04 lts. I think i was wrong when using sleep. It blocked all the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Function.prototype.clone = function() {
    var that = this;
    var temp = function temporary() { return that.apply(this, arguments); };
    for(var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = this[key];
        }
    }
    return temp;
};

var method = function () {
   var sleep = require('sleep');
   console.log("thread started", process.threadId);
   sleep.sleep(2);
   console.log("thread finished", process.threadId);
};

jxcore.tasks.addTask(method);
jxcore.tasks.addTask(method.clone());
jxcore.tasks.addTask(method.clone());
jxcore.tasks.addTask(method.clone());
```

Or:

```
var newmethod1 = method.clone();
jxcore.tasks.addTask(newmethod1);
jxcore.tasks.runOnce(newmethod1);
```

Comment: sleep command will interupt all thread, so I guess I have to setTimeout to test.